# How to recover the data stored under the root structure that are deactivated in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I encountered a problem in Apache IoTDB. When I tried to execute `deactivate schema template met from root.met.*`, the data stored under the `root.met.*` are gone and cannot be queried. How can I recover these data?